# c++ initialize char array of size "static * int" in template function

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, pointers, static

Is it possible to initialise a char array inside a template function with size contained in a static * int?

.header

```
static int * array_size;

template <class T>
void f(T value)
{
    char buffer[*array_size];
}
```

Or is there a way to initialize "array_size" so that the template has a default value to use?

Comment: Why do you want to use a pointer here? The expression inside the `[]` must be a constant expression, therefore you cannot use modifiable types. `static constexpr int const* array_size = &my_size;` (where `my_size` is e.g. a `constexpr int`) is possible, but not sure why you want to use that.

Comment: i am trying to have a buffer that i can change its size

Comment: Array sizes must be known at compile time. You could use a `std::vector` instead of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`static int * array_size` won't work because the data inside the pointer is modifiable and thus cannot be determined at compile-time.

If you are using C++11 I would suggest

```
constexpr int array_size = 42;
```

If you cannot use C++11 I would use:

```
static const int array_size = 42;
```

In both cases you create your buffer like this:

```
char buffer[array_size];
```

So without the asterisk.

If you cannot find out the size of the buffer at compile time (so the size is dependant on runtime-decisions) you need to use a dynamic array, preferably encapsulated into a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> bufferVec(myDynamicSize); // Use any integer you want to
char *buffer = &bufferVec[0]; // Use this buffer as a standard array 
                              // with size myDynamicSize OR use the std::vector
                              // directly (much cleaner)
```

Answer (score 0):

Qualifyer for array_size must be constant, otherwhise you will end with **expected constant expression**. Static keyword is irrelevant.

```
const int array_size = 42;
char buffer[array_size];
```

Pointer dereferencing will not work even if the pointer points to a const

```
const int a = 42;
int const * const array_size = &a;
char buffer[array_size]; // error C2057: expected constant expression
```

You also might paste in the array_size via a template parameter:

```
template <class T, int array_size>
void f(T value)
{
  char buffer[array_size];
}

f<int, 42>(100);
```

Comment: *"Pointer dereferencing will not work even if the pointer points to a const"* It will work if *the pointer* has been declared `constexpr` (in this case).